# Android Centered Inner Layout

Tags: android, xml, android-layout

I need a box within a box, with ~33% of empty room at the top of the first box, and then another box below that. I need it to be centered. I would like this to essentially `fill_parent` on a mobile phone, but on a tablet (the primary device for this app), it should remain the same size but be centered in the middle of the screen. How can I do this?

I'm including to examples since it's a little hard for me to explain.

**Mobile**

```
|---------------------------|
|     ~33% Blank space      |
|                           |
|  |---------------------|  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |      Login Box      |  |
|  |      Password       |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |                     |  |
|  |---------------------|  |
|---------------------------|
```

**Tablet**

```
|---------------------------------------|
|           ~33% Blank space            |
|                                       |
|        |---------------------|        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |      Login Box      |        |
|        |      Password       |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |                     |        |
|        |---------------------|        |
|---------------------------------------|
```

**Edit**  Here is the XML I currently have. I'm not getting intellisense for anything, (I usually get suggestions), and I'm getting a cast exception with multiple layouts. Is there something wrong with the XML?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:weightSum="1"
    >
    <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/topSpacer"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        ></LinearLayout>
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/bottomSection"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".67"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/loginSection"
            android:layout_width="320dip"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:background="#FFFFFF"
            >
            <TextView
                android:text="" 
                android:id="@+id/errorMessage" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            />
            <TextView 
                android:text="Please login using your active directory credentials." 
                android:id="@+id/loginMessage" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            />
            <AutoCompleteTextView 
                android:id="@+id/loginUsername" 
                android:text="Username" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
            />
            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/loginPassword"
                android:text="Password"
                android:password="true"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <Button
                android:id="@+id/loginButton"
                android:text="Login"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            />
            <TextView 
                android:text="results" 
                android:id="@+id/resultsMessage" 
                android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
            />
        </LinearLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try a combination of linear layouts that utilize the `weightSum` property.  Also notice that the inner box's width is fixed as you mentioned on the tablet you don't want it to re-size.

Try this:

***EDIT: i used a relative layout to get the inner box centered ***

```
<LinearLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical"
  android:weightSum="1">
<LinearLayout android:id="@+id/thirtyThreePercentSpacer" 
        android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight=".33">
</LinearLayout>
<RelativeLayout android:id="@+id/RelativeLayout01" 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_weight=".67">

            <LinearLayout android:id="@+id/innerBox" 
                    android:layout_width="320dip" 
                    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true">
            </LinearLayout>

  </RelativeLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Yeah..I am trying to use nested layouts, but when I use it..I'm getting a cast exception on my UI Widgets..any ideas?

Comment: Where is that exception being thrown? In the XML or your Activity?

Comment: I believe in the XML, because it force closes upon opening. I posted my XML.

Comment: The XML you posted looks clean .. Eclipse didn't throw any errors for me in the XML .. can you use the Debugger and step through your code to see on what line in your Java file it may be failing?

Comment: ...turns out the problem was with Eclipse. I cleaned the project, and now it's working. -____-

Comment: Actually, the LinearLayout shows up, but the widgets inside do not.

Comment: add `android:orientation="vertical"` to the `loginSection` .. that displayed all of your elements for me

Answer (score 1):

You can use different layouts for smartphones and tablets.

Put that in your `layout` folder:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="login box"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

And for tablets you can use something like this under `layout-large`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <FrameLayout
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1">
    </FrameLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:layout_weight="2"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="login box"/>
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

In that case you should adjust the width of the login box to your needs.

Maybe you could do some things with the same layout but in general the layouts for those device classes will differ extremely. To improve this you can design the login box once and `include` it from those layouts (see http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).